# Google Analytics on open email

Tags: email, google-analytics

I've been reading a lot of information about of track how much people read an email I've sent. I've been searching on this forum, and also reading on official analytics documentation.

I've created an html with the following code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <img src="http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid={MY-UA}&cid=555&t=event&ec=email&ea=open&cs=newsletter&cm=email&cn=CAMPANA" style="visibility: hidden;" />
  </body>
</html>
```

With this I'm trying to make an emulation of which code I'll include on my email.
The problem comes when I go to my Analytics account and I just get real time information. But I want to get a register of all email written.

I've tried to go behaviour > Events. And there is no information written right there. But as I've said before if I go realtime I can see 1 person is "visiting" my website. Why is this happening?

I get some information example from:
https://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2013/06/17/email-tracking-google-analytics/

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid={MY-UA}&cid={UNIQUEID}&t=event&ec=email&ea=open&cs=newsletter&cm=email&cn=CAMPANA" style="visibility: hidden;" />
```

Change the cid value in cid=555 to cid= {add unique identifer here per user or email}

This is because Google uses a parameter named client ID to definite users, this has to unique per user otherwise all hits will look like it is coming from the same user.

Note: make sure no PII is used in the hit

Comment: Thanks but it finally worked, seems like i've to wait at least one day to get all info